# using regular expressions in xpath and xml

Tags: xml, regex, xpath

i have a small problem in using regular expressions along with xml and xpath.

I have an xml file like this

messages.xml

```
<message>
  <text>dog goes woof</text>
</message>
<message>
  <text>cat goes meow, dog goes woof, fish goes blub</text>
</message>
```

and then i have an xpath expression which allows me to select the text node which has text node as dog goes woof like this

```
   String expression = "//text[.='dog goes woof']";
   NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(messages, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

here "messages" is the Document variable which refers to the messages.xml file.

when i iterate through the nodeList, it selects only the first text node. I want to select the other text node too which contains dog goes woof. So how can i specify in the xpath expression to check for text nodes which contains dog goes woof in them.

please let me know how to do it.

thanks

Comment: You asked 8 Question and accepted only 1 Answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `contains()` function or if you really want to use regex you can use the `matches()` function

```
"//text[contains(text(), 'dog goes woof')]"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use contains in the xpath, example like `//text()[contains(., 'dog goes woof')]`