# Splinter find_by_xpath: using regex for element text()

Tags: python, regex, selenium, xpath, splinter

I am running a browser test with splinter and have a page with a large table. I want to locate all `<tr>` elements that contain a `<td>` with some nicely-formatted date in their text, like the one highlighted here:

[image]

It's easy to find the rows with specific text, e.g., via:

`browser.find_by_xpath('//tr[.//td[contains(text(), "September")]]')`

So then I tried something like the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865786/using-regular-expressions-in-xpath-and-xml) to find text() with the general date pattern (help with simplifying my regex is welcome, too):

```
exp = '[A-Z][a-z]+\\s[1-9]{1,2},\\s[0-9]{4}'
browser.find_by_xpath('//tr[.//td[matches(text(), "{0}")]]'.format(exp))
```

This doesn't work (and I did verify that the regex works in isolation). Nor does:

`browser.find_by_xpath('//tr[.//td[matches(., "{0}")]]'.format(exp))`

Provided my browser allows XPath 2.0, how can I find the elements correctly?

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: Looks like Firefox 41.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both latest Firefox and Chrome don't support XPath 2.0. Here are the relevant open issues:

- [Support XPath 2.0 in XPath evaluate](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=474137)
- [Bug 396966 - Xpath 2.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=396966)

You have to approach it without using `matches()`. For instance, you may filter the list of `tr` you find in Python by taking the [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and using `datetime.strptime()`. Sample:

```
from datetime import datetime

for tr in browser.find_by_tag("tr"):
    sorted_on = tr.find_by_css(".sorted-on")

    try:
        datetime.strptime(sorted_on.text, "%B %d, %Y")
    except ValueError:
        continue
```